# Design butterfly chart using Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, echarts

I'm not able to design butterfly chart using highcharts and echarts, I want to plot it as.
[image]

Please help me to achieve this

Comment: Please add the code of the chart with some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic config of the butterfly chart is based on the `bar` type of series and properly spaced `yAxis` and `xAxis`. Other configurations depend on your requirements. Here is a basic config example:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    width: 600
  },

  xAxis: [{
    categories: ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3', 'Category 4', 'Category 5'],
    offset: -300
  }],

  yAxis: [{
      reversed: true,
      width: '40%',
    },
    {
      offset: 0,
      width: '40%',
      left: '60%',
    }
  ],

  series: [{
    data: [50, 60, 70, 79, 10],
  }, {
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [10, 30, 30, 20, 70],
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/os8jcypr/

**Expanded demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1Lp5rqjg/